# File permissions on EC2 Instance

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I keep getting this issue on EC2. I've a cron that is run by root user. Whenever this tries to access files (`fopen` in read-only or `filesize`) in a folder that has 777, it fails with an error similar to `"Warning: filesize(): stat failed for /var/www/.."`

It is becoming increasingly difficult to predict this behaviour. Has anyone faced similar issues? Or any recommended way of setting up users and groups? I'm running it on a default setup. Safe mode is turned off as well.

Comment: if it's run by root it's not a permissions issue (root has access to any file). this error is usually issued when the file doesn't exist.

Comment: @andreimarinescu you are right.

Comment: great, good to know! added my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added my comment as an answer :

If the cron job is run by root then it's not a permissions issue (root has access to any file). This error is usually issued when the file doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a php guy but here is my best guess. The directory has 777 permission but what about the file's permissions inside that directory. Have you tried running `chmod` on said directory with `-R` option?

From `man chmod`:

```
-R, --recursive
              change files and directories recursively
```